# while using tightvnc the host computer resolution cannot be changed

Tags: vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

So when I connect my computer through vnc, the host computer displays the resolution of 640x480. Going to screen resolution, the display is set to "display device on: Mobile PC Display" 
the host computer is not plugged into a monitor but that should not even matter, as I am connected using vnc using a tightvnc client.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the resolution when you start the tightvnc session on the server

```
tightvncserver -geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT -depth XX :1
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... no -geometry option. (Version 2.7.10. What version are you running cantsay?) And no -geometry option is listed in the documentation: 
http://www.tightvnc.com/doc/win/TightVNC_2.7_for_Windows_Server_Command-Line_Options.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I am on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine and use TightVNC. I start VNC server with geomtry option specifying a screen size slightly smaller than my full screen on client.

```
$ tightvncserver -geometry 1680x1050 -depth 24
```

The version of vncserver is given as

```
$ tightvncserver -version

Xvnc version TighVNC-1.3.10
```

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is "default monitor", you can change the minimum resolution on boot/configure.txt

uncomment :

```
# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
```

Comment: where is `boot/configure.txt`?